# String Input line 4 Error, I cannot seem to figure out what it is

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class StringInput{
    public static void main (String args[]);{
        String Name "StringInput";
        System.out.print ("Enter your name: ");
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            InputStreamReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
                name = reader.readline();
                catchException e;{
            }//Exception
            System.out.println ("Hello"+Name+"How are you?");
    }//main
}//class
```

That is the code that I was doing, theres one error. Line 4, I can't figure out what it is.

We were doing it in class (I just started Computer Programming 12) and we didn't have time to finish it and everything.

If someone could help me figure out what is wrong with line 4 that'd be really helpful.

Thanks ! :)

Removed the semi colon, still get String Name "StringInput";
                   ^
1 error

Process completed.

Comment: `(String args[]);{` remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon(`;`) after main method:

Change this:

```
public static void main (String args[]);{
```

to

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
```

Another error in your code is related to try/catch usage:

Change this:

```
 name = reader.readline();
            catchException e;{
        }//Exception
```

to

```
  try {
         name = reader.readline();
    catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }//Exception
```

**Final Note**: Learn the language syntax first before jumping to coding.

Comment: This is totally a typographical error; shouldn't really be a question.

Comment: @ZachLecky check the updated answer. I strongly recommend you to spend time in reading and learning the java syntax .